# Prolog Wildcard

Tags: prolog

I have the following clauses:

```
a(1).
a(a).
b(3).
b(a).
c(A,B) :- b(B),!,a(A).
c(X,_) :- a(X),b(X).
```

Query `c(A,B)` only returns two solutions: `A = 1, B = 3 and A = a, B = 3.`
I traced `c(A,B)` and noticed that Prolog doesn't even try the second clause `(c(X,_))`. Why is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Prolog cut** predicate, or '!', eliminates choices is a Prolog derivation tree.

Please check its role [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Cuts_and_Negation#The_cut)

Comment: Thank you! It seems I misunderstood the role of the cut. I thought it committed to the first choice, but only for the clause being analysed. I thought that encountering a cut in one rule had no consequences on trying other rules.